# Could not find artifact com.sun.kvem:kenv:jar:2.2 in central

Tags: java, maven-plugin, proguard

I am trying to compile the source code of Proguard 4.6 in a maven project. The code has a dependency on:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.kvem</groupId>
    <artifactId>kenv</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

When I try compile it, I get:

```
Failed to execute goal on project proguard:
Could not resolve dependencies for project net.sf.proguard:proguard:jar:4.6:
Could not find artifact com.sun.kvem:kenv:jar:2.2 in central
(http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

When I browse central ([here](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-1865595781)), there is indeed no such jar in the central repository.

I don't know what kvem is. Why is it declared as `type=jar` in the pom.xml and why isn't it in central repository? How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.sun.kvem -DartifactId=kenv -Dversion=kenv -Dfile=com.sun.kvem-2.2.jar -Dpackaging=jar  -Dgenerate-pom=true
```

Comment: Where I can get `com.sun.kvem-2.2.jar`?

Comment: **Edit:** It's in Sun Java Wireless Toolkit (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javame-419430.html#sun_java_wireless_toolkit-2.5.2_01b-oth-JPR)