# Kenv Library not found when downloading from maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I'm trying to download a jar from maven, I always download jar's from maven and I never run into an error. I am trying to download the jar that can be found on this page.

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.kvem/kenv/2.2
```

How ever when I try to download the jar, It shows 404 Not Found.

This is the download URL `http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/kvem/kenv/2.2/kenv-2.2.jar`

I looked every where for the jar, but I can't seem to find it. I wan't the .jar file to include in my project as a library. Can someone point me to where I can download this jar or provide the jar for me?

Comment: You'd better upload your pom.xml, it's not easy for us to trace the issue without that.

Comment: @Gearon I don't have a pom.xml, I don't want to use maven/gradle, I want the `.jar` file to include it to my project, I can't seem to download the `.jar` file from the maven page.

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221759/could-not-find-artifact-com-sun-kvemkenvjar2-2-in-central to see if it is helpful to you